caught Snapshot missing on Livewire component with id:
Whey i try to filter via buttons i get this error
caught Snapshot missing on Livewire component with id:
This is my code
<div>
    <div class="flex flex-col w-full gap-6 mx-auto lg:flex-row">
        {{-- SIDEBAR --}}
        <aside class="top-0 w-full max-h-screen p-4 overflow-y-auto bg-white rounded-lg shadow-lg lg:w-2/6 xl:w-1/5 dark:bg-gray-800 lg:sticky lg:top-10"
            x-data="{ isOpen: false, showFilter: {{ !$hideFilter ? 'true' : 'false' }} }">
            <div class="mb-4 lg:hidden">
                <button @click="isOpen = !isOpen" class="w-full px-4 py-2 font-semibold text-white bg-blue-500 rounded-lg">
                    <span x-text="isOpen ? 'Hide Filters' : 'Show Filters'"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
 
            <div x-show="isOpen || window.innerWidth >= 1024" class="lg:block" :class="{ 'hidden lg:block': !isOpen }"
                @resize.window="isOpen = window.innerWidth >= 1024">
                {{-- Top Categories --}}
                <div class="mb-6">
                    <span class="flex items-center gap-2 mb-4 font-bold lg:text-xl text-foreground"> Top Categories</span>
                    <div class="flex flex-wrap gap-2">
                        @foreach ($items as $item)
                            @if ($item->active)
                                <a wire:key="item-{{ $item->id }}" href="{{ route('items.show', $item->slug) }}" wire:navigate
                                class="px-4 py-2 text-sm transition bg-blue-100 rounded-md dark:bg-blue-700 lg:text-base text-foreground hover:bg-blue-200 dark:hover:bg-blue-600">
                                    {{ $item->name }}
                                </a>
                            @endif
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex justify-center mt-4">
                        <a href="{{ route('items.index') }}"
                        class="px-4 py-2 text-sm text-white transition bg-pink-500 rounded-md hover:bg-pink-600">See all items</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
 
                {{-- Search by Location --}}
                <div class="mb-6">
                    <span class="flex items-center gap-2 mb-4 font-bold lg:text-xl text-foreground"> Search by Location</span>
                    <div class="flex flex-wrap gap-2">
                        @foreach ($locations as $location)
                            @if ($location->active)
                                <a wire:key="location-{{ $location->id }}" href="{{ route('locations.incrementClickCount', ['code' => $location->code]) }}" wire:navigate
                                class="w-10 h-10 overflow-hidden transition border-2 border-gray-300 rounded-full dark:border-gray-600 hover:border-pink-500 dark:hover:border-pink-400">
                                    <img src="{{ asset('flags/' . strtolower($location->code) . '.svg') }}" alt="{{ $location->name }}" class="w-full mx-auto rounded-lg">
                                </a>
                            @endif
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex justify-center mt-4">
                        <a href="{{ route('locations.index') }}" wire:navigate
                        class="px-4 py-2 text-sm text-white transition bg-pink-500 rounded-md hover:bg-pink-600">See all locations</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
 
                {{-- Filter by Type --}}
                <div>
                    <div>
                        @if (!$hideFilter)
                            <div class="mt-6">
                                <span class="flex items-center gap-2 mb-4 font-bold lg:text-xl text-foreground"> Filter by Type</span>
                                <div class="flex flex-row items-center gap-2">
                                    <button wire:click="setType('all')"
                                            class="flex-1 px-4 py-2 rounded-lg text-sm hover:bg-secondary hover:text-foreground focus:outline-none @if ($type == 'all') bg-blue-500 text-white @else text-foreground @endif"> All</button>
                                    <button wire:click="setType('option1')"
                                            class="flex-1 px-4 py-2 rounded-lg text-sm hover:bg-secondary hover:text-foreground focus:outline-none @if ($type == 'option1') bg-pink-500 text-white @else text-foreground @endif"> Option 1</button>
                                    <button wire:click="setType('option2')"
                                            class="flex-1 px-4 py-2 rounded-lg text-sm hover:bg-secondary hover:text-foreground focus:outline-none @if ($type == 'option2') bg-blue-500 text-white @else text-foreground @endif"> Option 2</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </aside>
 
        {{-- ITEMS LIST --}}
        <main class="flex flex-col items-center w-full gap-10 ml-auto lg:w-4/6 xl:w-4/5" wire:scroll="loadMore">
            <div class="flex flex-col items-center w-full gap-10 px-4 py-6 text-center transition rounded-lg lg:py-10 sm:px-8 lg:px-20 bg-gradient-to-tr from-pink-200 via-sky-500/30 to-pink-200 max-w-7xl">
                <h1 class="flex items-center max-w-4xl gap-2 text-xl font-bold text-center sm:text-2xl lg:text-4xl text-foreground">
                    {!! $title !!}
                </h1>
                <div>
                    @if (!empty($description))
                        <h2 class="max-w-3xl text-base text-center sm:text-lg lg:text-xl text-foreground">
                            {{ $description }}
                        </h2>
                    @endif
                </div>
            </div>
 
            {{-- SECTION CONTENT --}}
            <div class="flex flex-col items-center w-full gap-4 text-left max-w-7xl">
                @foreach ($sections as $section)
                    <div>
                        <article wire:key="section-{{ $section->id }}" class="w-full prose max-w-none dark:prose-invert prose-a:text-sky-500 hover:prose-a:text-sky-600 hover:prose-a:underline prose-h2:font-bold prose-h3:font-semibold">
                            {!! $section->content !!}
                        </article>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
            </div>
 
            <div class="flex flex-row flex-wrap justify-center gap-x-4 gap-y-6 max-w-7xl">
                @foreach ($itemsList as $item)
                    <div>
                        @if ($item->active)
                            <livewire:item-card :item="$item" :key="'item-card-'.$item->id" wire:key="item-card-{{ $item->id }}" class="flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 w-full sm:w-[190px] md:w-[220px] lg:w-[250px] xl:w-[280px]" />
                        @endif
                    </div>
                @endforeach
            </div>
 
            <div>
                @if (!$noMoreItems)
                    <div class="flex items-center justify-center" x-intersect="$wire.loadMore()">
                        <div class="w-8 h-8 border-4 border-pink-500 border-dotted rounded-full animate-spin"></div>
                    </div>
                @endif
            </div>
 
            <div>
                @if ($noMoreItems)
                    <div class="flex items-center justify-center">
                        <p class="text-sm text-foreground">No more items to load.</p>
                    </div>
                @endif
            </div>
        </main>
    </div>
</div>

try entangling boolean to an alpine property, and then do x-show

I assume you are using Livewire 3
Remove wire:key="item-card-{{ $item->id }}" from the <livewire:item-card ..... /> nested component like this:
@if ($item->active)

    <livewire:item-card :item="$item"
                        :key="'item-card-'.$item->id"
                        class="flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 w-full sm:w-[190px] md:w-[220px] lg:w-[250px] xl:w-[280px]"
    />

@endif

Nested component inserted in loops needs only a :key as documented here
wire:key instead is needed when you are rendering HTML elements in loops as documented here
